# Can't send call to client

Tags: node.js, tcp

I can not get the module to send the Server Call Data to the client (see line 36) so that the client can then return the sensor data.

I have run out of ideas, have tried lots of things.

Also if I uncomment 'use strict' why is console.log called as an error?

Note : I have included fhe file .jshintrc in the development directory to ensure ES6 is validated.

The code is as follows;

```
// See https://techbrij.com/node-js-tcp-server-client-promisify

//'use strict';

const ServerComms = {  // Server Comms Data
  serverIP    :"192.168.100.199",
  serverPort  : 9000
};  // End ClientComms

var ClientComms = {  // Client Comms Data
  clientIP    :"192.168.100.101",
  clientPort  : 9000
};  // End ClientComms

var ServerCall = {  // Server job call to client
  clientIP    : ClientComms.clientIP, // '192.168.100.101', Same as ClientComms.clientIP
  jobID       : 1
};  // End ServerCall

const net = require('net');

class MyServer {
  constructor() {
    this.address = ServerComms.serverIP;
    this.port = ServerComms.serverPort;
  this.init();
  }  // End constructor


  init() {
    let server = this;

    let onClientConnected = (socket) => {

      console.log(`Sending request job to RSU : ${ServerComms.serverPort} ${ServerComms.serverIP}`);
      server.socket.write( ServerCall.clientIP, ServerCall.jobID );  // Send request and data to client so that client can respond with remote sensor data.


      let clientName = `${ClientComms.clientIP} : ${ClientComms.clientPort}`;
      console.log(`New client is connected: ${clientName}`);

      socket.on('data', (clientData) => {
        console.log(`${clientName} Says: ${clientData}`);
        socket.write(clientData);
        socket.write('exit');
      });

      socket.only('close', () => {
        console.log(`Connection from ${clientName} closed`);
      });

      socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(`Connection ${clientName} error: ${err.message}`);
      });

    };  // End onClientConnect.

    //server.connection = net.createServer(onClientConnected);
    server.connection = net.createServer(  onClientConnected, function(){
      console.log(`Server created at: ${ServerComms.serverIP} : ${ServerComms.serverPort}`);
    });

    server.connection.listen(ServerComms.serverPort, ServerComms.serverIP, function() {
      console.log(`Server started at: ${ServerComms.serverIP} : ${ServerComms.serverPort}`);
    });  // End server.connection.listen

  }  // End init

}  // End class Server

module.exports = MyServer;
```

The calling module is as follows;

```
// To test server, use following code in another file and run it

const Server = require('./ServerCommsV05.js');

new Server();
```

Comment: If you're having trouble where even the console.log directive is not showing the correct output have you checked whether the file you're editing is being loaded? Maybe add an additional console.log in `listen` callback and verify the file you're working in is what's being used.